# Is there any way to jump to the ground floor?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

When you tap at the top of the screen, you jump to the very top floor.
Is there an equivalent to jump to the ground floor (i.e. not the quick button for the elevator, but something which is there all the time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, no there is not.  The only method anyone has come up with is to leave Mos Espa Cafe or something close to the bottom level empty of bitizens and use the ! notifier as a quick way down.  This is not desirable on several levels, though.  You lose revenue, and it makes the function of the ! notifier not reliable for other levels.

Comment: Thanks, that is pretty clever but the disadvantages outweigh the benefit. Is there anywhere which we can submit to the developers to request this feature?

Comment: Yes. Support@disneymobile.com

Comment: Why not move Panna City Medicines for this?  This one would typically be empty more often, as Bitizens don't have this for their dream job.

Comment: @Tim Perfectly viable option.  PCM doesn't carry much stock to begin with.  Yet, the function of the ! marker is still significantly diminished.